# Как проставлять отбивку в числа?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Использую JS, regexp

```
'10000000000 '.replace(/(\d{2,3})(\d{3})\s/, '$1&ampthinsp;$2')
```

Нужно бы любые по длине числа обрабатывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'10000000000'.replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,'$& ')
```

Comment: Простите, а что, если 1000 должен быть без отбивки? Никак не получается придумать как изменить ваше выражение.

Comment: Это уже извращение какое-то. Поставь условие:

    digit = digit.length > 4 ? digit.replace(...) : digit;

Comment: Так не получится, я ведь в тексте всё это подменяю, а не в скрипте

Comment: Соболезную.